# How to convert the input format of date to a specific new format in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, date

**How to convert the value in the below input to the format of** `9:15 pm, 2nd May 2023`

**Input**: `2023-11-20T17:09:08.000Z`

---

**What I tried**:  I tried to use SimpleDateFormat, But I couldn't get the appropriate format

`val curFormater = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")`

Any other attempts result in a parse error ... Is there a proper standard way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm confused. Why did you think that format could possibly work? It doesn't describe your input and doesn't describe your output. You need to [A] ditch the old and broken API and use `java.time` instead, then [B] make a `DateTimeFormatter` (the non-broken equivalent of SimpleDateFormat) for the input format, and _another_ one for the output format, then it's a simple task from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is. As rzwitserloot already [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77557244/how-to-convert-the-input-format-of-date-to-a-specific-new-format-in-android/77557407#comment136728274_77557244), immediately ditch the obsolete `SimplateDateFormat`. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Then you need to do the following:

##### 1. Parse the string

to a proper date and time model. I picked `OffsetDateTime` here, as your input string contains a date component, a time component and a time zone thingy (the `Z`).

```java
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(input);
```

Since the *input* format is conform to the ISO 8601 standard, you don't have to specify a format; it will parse the string out-of-the-box.

##### 2. Define the right output format

and you can use `format` to form the desired text. This looks like it:

```java
String output = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a, d MMMM uuuu", Locale.UK));
```

##### Ordinal suffix

But then there is a small problem. You are using an English *ordinal suffix* (st, nd, rd, th), and there is no such formatting pattern to output such. Fortunately, you can use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to have a more fine-grained control over the output. We can use `appendText(Map<Long, String>)` to look up a value mapped to a certain comnponent field.

```java
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("h:mm a, d")
    .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, ordinalSuffixes)
    .appendPattern(" MMMM uuuu")
    .toFormatter(Locale.UK);
```

This will use the day of the month as a long to lookup *that* specific value in the given map. So we will need to make sure that we have a map which returns the correct values for the correct keys.

```java
Map<Long, String> ordinalSuffixes = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 31)
    .mapToObj(n -> Map.entry((long) n, switch (n) {
        case 1, 21, 31 -> "st";
        case 2, 22 -> "nd";
        case 3, 23 -> "rd";
        default -> "th";
    }))
    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Good call. I have updated the question.

Comment: BTW `Locale.ENGLISH` will return uppercase AM/PM; `Locale.UK` lowercase

Comment: Good answer! There are so many good things for a beginner to learn from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use new java.time api, it fixes lots of deficiencies from the older standard api. Since you are using android, you may worry if java.time is available. According to:

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/OffsetDateTime

OffsetDateTime was added in api level 26, but with desugaring enabled you can use it on every platform - read here more on that: [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)

Below I include code for parsing string using java.api and legacy api. I include legacy api code more to present how much its complicated.

```
package org.example;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String input = "2023-11-20T17:09:08.000Z";
        //String input = "2023-11-20T12:09:08.000-05:00";

        // Using Java 8 time api
        String formattedString = convertTimeStringUsingJavaTime(input);
        System.out.println(formattedString); //5:09 PM, 20th November 2023

        // Legacy api, not recommended
        formattedString = convertTimeStringUsingLegacyApi(input);
        System.out.println(formattedString); //5:09 PM, 20th November 2023
    }

    private static String convertTimeStringUsingJavaTime(String input) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(input);
        String dayOfMonthSuffix = getDayOfMonthSuffix(odt.getDayOfMonth());
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a, d'" + dayOfMonthSuffix + "' MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return odt.format(formatter);
    }

    private static String convertTimeStringUsingLegacyApi(String input) throws ParseException {
        TimeZone timeZone;
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat;

        if(input.endsWith("Z")) {
            inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
            timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
            inputFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
        } else {
            inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String timeZoneString = input.substring(input.length() - 6);
            timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + timeZoneString);
        }

        Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a, 'd' MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        outputFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);

        //get suffix for day of month
        int dayOfMonth = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("d").format(date));
        String dayOfMonthSuffix = getDayOfMonthSuffix(dayOfMonth);

        String formattedDate = outputFormat.format(date);
        // insert suffix after day of month
        formattedDate = formattedDate.replaceAll(" d ", " " + dayOfMonth + dayOfMonthSuffix + " ");
        return formattedDate;
    }

    private static String getDayOfMonthSuffix(final int day) {
        if (day >= 11 && day <= 13) {
            return "th";
        }
        switch (day % 10) {
            case 1:  return "st";
            case 2:  return "nd";
            case 3:  return "rd";
            default: return "th";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
String inputDate = "2023-11-20T17:09:08.000Z";
        
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(inputDate);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, java.time.ZoneId.of("UTC"));

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a, d MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String outputDate = dateTime.format(formatter);

        System.out.println(outputDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I tried to use SimpleDateFormat, But I couldn't get the appropriate format ..."*

Here is an example.

```java
String s = "2023-11-20T17:09:08.000Z";
SimpleDateFormat f;
long t;
f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
t = f.parse(s).getTime();
s = "%tl:%<tM %<tp, %<te %<tb %<tY".formatted(t);
```

Output

```
5:09 pm, 20 Nov 2023
```

Applying the *[ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_numeral)*  suffix takes slightly more effort.

```java
String a, b, c, s = "2023-11-20T17:09:08.000Z";
SimpleDateFormat f;
long t;
int v;
f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
t = f.parse(s).getTime();
a = "%tl:%<tM %<tp, ".formatted(t);
b = "%te".formatted(t);
c = " %tb %<tY".formatted(t);
b += switch (v = Integer.parseInt(b)) {
    case 11, 12, 13 -> "th";
    default -> switch (v % 10) {
        case 1 -> "st";
        case 2 -> "nd";
        case 3 -> "rd";
        default -> "th";
    };
};
s = a + b + c;
```

Output

```
5:09 pm, 20th Nov 2023
```